# Passing string between forms returns null

Tags: c#, winforms

In the program you enter with a username brought from a database. I need to pass that username to another form but when I do it, it returns null in the second form although in the first form it appears.( "Jugador" is the class from where I bring the name).

```
public Usuario()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private string _Message;
public string Message
{
    get { return _Message; }
    set { _Message = strName; }
}
public string strName;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text!="")
    {
        Jugador jug = new Jugador();
        jug.Traemelo(textBox1.Text);
        strName = textBox1.Text;
        elegirTipo us = new elegirTipo();
        us.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }


}
```

And in my other form i have this.(Usuario is the first form)

```
private void silabas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Usuario usu = new Usuario();
    juga.Traemelo(usu.Message);
}
```

I've got to add that in the middle of these forms I pass by one but doens't need the variable there.
Thanks for the help! I really don't know what is happening because I've done this other times.

Comment: `Usuario usu = new Usuario();` you have new instance in `silabas_Load`, you lost the values with a new instance. Add string variable in `Usario` and set `strName` before show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I personally would do is to create a static class and hold the values in it. This would also let me not to instantiate the class every time I need to use it.

```
public static class Jugador 
{
    //ctor if needed
    public static string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in your code where you both set or get the values of the username:

```
//login process
Jugador.Username = "some username";

//in application (get)
textbox1.Text = Jugador.Username;
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Usuario.cs
public string Message { get; set; }
...
Silabas silabas = new Silabas(this);

// Silabas.cs
public Silabas(Usuario usuario)
{
  // Here you can access the usuario.Message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance:

```
     public string Message
     {
       get { return _Message; }
       set { _Message = value } // instead of strName;
     }
```

no `Message=something` (set is never called)

_Message seems to compete with strName. One variable should be enough.

EDIT: Combined to this:

```
    public Usuario()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
     private string _Message;
     public string Message
     {
       get { return _Message; }
       set { _Message = value; }
     }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        Jugador jug = new Jugador();
        jug.Traemelo(textBox1.Text);
        Message = textBox1.Text;
        elegirTipo us = new elegirTipo();
        us.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is since you are creating a new instance i.e. Usuario usu = new Usuario(); of the object in the other class, the value becomes null. I would use a static variable. In your Usuario class use

```
public static string strName{get;set;}
```

Now to set the value say `Usuario.strName = textBox1.Text;`

in your other class here say,

```
 private void silabas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        juga.Traemelo(Usuario.strName);

    }
```